# Передача классов в подпрограмму

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте. У меня следующая проблема: существует абстрактный класс А, от него наследуются два класса: В и С. Как поступить если на этапе компиляции не известно какой класс В или С будет передан в процедуру? То есть в процессе выполнения программы в процедуру нужно передавать любой из этих двух классов и процедура должна иметь именно один параметр. Как тут применить метаклассы если это нужно?

Answer (score 6):

В таких случаях процедура в качестве параметра принимает класс А. Например:

```
type
  A = class
  end;

type
  B = class(A)
 end;

type
  C = class (A)
  end;

......

procedure foo(arg: A);
begin
 ....
end;

..............
var 
  b: B;
  c: C;  
begin
  b = B.Create();
  C = C.Create();
  foo(b);
  foo(c);    
end;
```

Comment: а не будет abstract error от того что класс А абстрактный?

Comment: !? Мне казалось, что необходимо передавать указатели на экземпляры классов. Или паскали теперь настолько умные, что уже оптимизируют такие передачи!?

Comment: @ibr, не будет. Передаете то вы конкретные классы, а не абстрактные. Советую почитать побольше о полиморфизме и с чем его едят.

@gecube, зачем передавать указатели?? Все объекты, которые объявляются в дельфи и так не "настоящие" (в С++ смысле), а ссылки (как в Java). При передаче объекта в качестве параметра создается копия ссылки на этот объект (что по сути мало отличается от передачи указателя). Эти принципы были еще в Delphi 5 (с более ранними не работал), а не появились "теперь".

Comment: @ibr, не обязательно расходовать свои очки уважения, достаточно "Принять ответ" кликнув по галочке, если он вам помог.

Comment: <i>  зачем передавать указатели? </i>

затем, что я привык к С/C++/asm. И меня это малость удивило.